# What do I put into LocationManager call permission if statement

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I've been looking all over stackoverflow and search sites and have found so many different answers or outdated answers so I'm not sure how to answer this question. I am trying to get the latitude and longitude to use for my app. I've gotten to the point that I know to use location manager but then it calls for call permission.I've tried to find solutions on how to use it but there are so many answers with so many different views on whether those answers are correct. Here is my code, can some help me find the solution to what to put in the call permission for location manager and whether this code and get me the longitude and latitude? The results will be used in a fragment.

These are the permissions in my manifest file:ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, INTERNET and
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

```
 public class LocationFinder extends TestFragment implements LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = "LocationFragment";
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private static double latitude;
private static double longitude;

public LocationFinder() {


mLocationManager =(LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);




    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}





@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    latitude = location.getLatitude();

    longitude = location.getLongitude();

}



@Override

public void onStatusChanged(String s) {



}



@Override

public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {



}



@Override

public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {



}

   public static double getLatitude(){
    return latitude;
}

public static double getLongitude(){
    return longitude;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the app's permissions for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, you do run `checkSelfPermission` as you have done:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {  }
```

As your TODO states, you need to call requestPermissions:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 378);
```

where `378` is any integer you like (used next to check the result of the request):

Next the result of the request must be processed via an overriding method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 378) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // do whatever you need with permissions
        } else {
            // display a message or request again
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is correct, my code is not crashing but is the user supposed to grant permission? If so that prompt is not showing up when I run my app. I'm also not sure what I'm supposed to put in the if statement of the onRequestPermissionResult, is it the location part of my code. I can provide the rest of my code if my question isn't clear.

Comment: Wherever you put the first if statement (containing `checkSelfPermission`) in the code is when it will ask the user for permissions - I typically solve this by creating a splash screen for the app and putting it in the class's `onCreate` method so it runs when the app first starts.  
In the `onRequestPermissionsResult` if statement you might want to set an instance variable to the last latitude/longtitude which you can get by creating a Location Service provider. This link may be useful: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current